# Hazelcast write-through map store pre-population on startup

Tags: java, hazelcast

I am currently doing a `POC` for developing a `distributed, fault tolerant, ETL ecosystem`. I have selected `Hazelcast` for for my `clustering (data+notification)` purpose. Googling through Hazelcast resources took me [to this link](http://highscalability.com/blog/2011/4/12/caching-and-processing-2tb-mozilla-crash-reports-in-memory-w.html) and it exactly matches how I was thinking to go about, using a map based solution.

I need to understand one point. Before that, allow me to give a canonical idea of our architecture:

Say `we have 2 nodes A,B running our server instance clustered through hazelcast`. One of them is a listener accepting requests (but can change on a fail over), say A.

A gets a request and puts it to a distributed map. This map is write-through backed by a persistent store and a single memory backup is configured on nodes.

Each instance has a local map entry listener, which on entry added event, would `(asynchronous/queuing)` process that entry and then remove it from the distributed map.

This is working as expected.

**Question:**

Say 10 requests have been received and distributed with 5 on each nodes. 2 entries on each node has been processed and now both instance crashes.

So there are total 6 entries present in the backing datastore now.

Now we bring up both the instances. As per documentation - "`As of 1.9.3 MapLoader has the new MapLoader.loadAllKeys API. It is used for pre-populating the in-memory map when the map is first touched/used"`

We implement `loadAllKeys()` by simply loading all the key values present in the store.

1. So does that mean there is a possibility where, both the instances will now load the 6 entries and process them (thus resulting in duplicate processing)? **Or** is it handled in a synchronized way so that loading is done only once in a cluster?
2. `On server startup I need to process the pending entries` (if any). I see that the data is loaded, however the entryAdded event is not fired. How can make the entryAdded event fire (or any other elegant way, by which I will know that there are pending entries on startup)?

Requesting suggestions.

Thanks,
Sutanu

Comment: For the 2nd issue as of now, I am having a method which would "get" the "local" keySets and process them. This is a onetime invocation just after Hazelcast is initialized. I was wondering if this is the best I could do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. on initialization, loadAllKeys() will be called which will return all 6 keys in the persistent store. Then each node will select the keys it owns and load them only. So A might load 2 entries, while B loads the remaining 4.
2. store.load doesn't fire entry listeners. How about this: right after initialization, after registering your listener, you can get the localEntries and process the existing ones.

Comment: Thanks for confirming on 1. For 2, yes now I am doing something similar as you have mentioned, was wondering if that will be the accepted way.

Comment: I had one more question. If I keep back-up count to 0 under such architecture, in that case if one node fails, then though the entry would be still present in the data store, but it won't be failed over to any other node (unless a new node starts up). Is this a correct understanding? Basically I am interested to understand how a cluster with data store backed map, but no back-ups would behave. Thanks for your help.